# TimeDistribution Wrapper Fails the Compilation

Tags: python, tensorflow, video, keras

I have an extremely simple cnn which i will be trying to bind to an rnn (but that in the future). For now, all I have is conv2D->maxpool>conv2d->maxpool->dense->dense. The CNN works well, no problems, compiles, runs.

'model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(..., input_shape=(32,32,1))
**RuntimeError: You must compile your model before using it.**

And of course, model.compile() is immediately after the model definition and .fit following the compile...
Hence, is it me not getting something right or it is really an issue with the current Keras build?

Comment: Could you please provide the full model code?

Comment: @today, yes, just a second

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that input_shape must be specified outside Conv2D and inside TimeDistributed. Keep in mind it must be 4D '(batch_size, width, height, channels)'